# FacebookSDK Request.newMeRequest never been called

Tags: android, facebook, request

I've got a problem - I'm developing an app with facebook login and also I need to get User data, for somewhat reason I cant receive this data in Request.newMeRequest, because its onCompleted method never been called. I see in logcat only Logged in/out messages. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("QWE", "Logged in...");
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                Log.i("QWE","onCompleted");
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.i("QWE", "User is "+ user.getUsername());
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("QWE", "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem here is that you've created a request, but you're not calling executeAsync on it, so the request is never made. Try:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        Log.i("QWE","onCompleted");
        if (user != null) {
            Log.i("QWE", "User is "+ user.getUsername());
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();  // <--- CHANGE IS HERE
```

Comment: Why do we need `.executeAsync();`, why not `.executeAndWait();` ?

Comment: You're free to call executeAndWait, just be sure to not call it in the main thread.

Comment: You mean in the `onCreate()` function?

Comment: If you call executeAndWait from the main thread (onCreate is called in the main thread), you'll see errors on later versions of android, because you shouldn't make network i/o calls on the main thread.

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh.... I'm ashamed of how long I've been stuck on this stupid thing and didn't notice the executeAsync...